# WPF - XAML - DataGridRow Style Trigger IsMouseOver tooltip data binding

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am trying to get a tool tip to show an image upon a mouse hover of a row inside of a DataGrid in WPF.

Here is a snippet of the XAML for the RowStyle:

```
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" >
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CNIsOnline,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.OfflineColor,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CNIsOnline,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.OnlineColor,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CNIsOnline,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.UnknownColor,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <Image Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding userimg}"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

I know **userimg** is set correctly because if I take this line:

```
<Image Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding userimg}"/>
```

And put it somewhere else in my XAML I see the image.  If I change the userimg (it's just a string to a path of a PNG) to a hard coded path it seems to work, so I know it is a datacontext issue.

I have tried several things including: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16173869/wpf-error-40-bindingexpression-path-error-property-not-found-on-object), [this](https://wpf.2000things.com/2011/08/30/375-binding-something-in-a-tooltip-to-a-property-on-the-parent-control/), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14161504/datacontext-of-datatemplate-in-tooltip-style-in-wpf), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510931/is-there-a-way-to-determine-where-a-wpf-binding-is-declared-created/14523290#14523290) but I am still struggling to get this image to show by using data binding.

I have also tried this with no luck either:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTip">
<Setter.Value>
    <Image Height="50" Width="50" Source={Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.userimg,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Setter.Value>
```

These are the errors that show up when I try to view the tooltip:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'userimg' property not found on 'object' ''DataRowView' (HashCode=6587426)'. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=6587426); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=6587426); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=6587426); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem='DataRowView' (HashCode=6587426); target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'userimg' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')

System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
```

Can someone please help, can't afford to loose anymore hair...

**UPDATE**

Thanks for the reply Andy, Here is my entire snippet of the datagrid:

```
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="187"  Name="DG1" Background="Transparent" Foreground="{Binding MyForegroundColor}" BorderThickness="0" HeadersVisibility="Column" CanUserAddRows="False" IsReadOnly="True" Opacity="1" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".3" />
            </Style>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{Binding MyAccentColor,Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrush_ValueConverter}}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{Binding MyForegroundColor,Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrush_ValueConverter}}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"  Color="{Binding MyAccentColor,Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrush_ValueConverter}}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{Binding MyForegroundColor,Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrush_ValueConverter}}"/>
            <Image x:Key="yuserimg" Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding userimg}"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="bold"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" >
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding yuserimg}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CNIsOnline,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.OfflineColor,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CNIsOnline,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.OnlineColor,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CNIsOnline,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.UnknownColor,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

However, when I hover over a row I don't see any tool tip pop up at all now.

**UPDATE 2**

I updated the binding to dynamicresource as such:

```
            <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".3" />
            </Style>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="{Binding MyAccentColor,Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrush_ValueConverter}}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{Binding MyForegroundColor,Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrush_ValueConverter}}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey}"  Color="{Binding MyAccentColor,Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrush_ValueConverter}}"/>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="{Binding MyForegroundColor,Converter={StaticResource ColorToSolidColorBrush_ValueConverter}}"/>
            <Image x:Key="yuserimg" Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding userimg}"/>
        </DataGrid.Resources>


            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow" >
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{DynamicResource yuserimg}"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CNIsOnline,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.OfflineColor,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CNIsOnline,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.OnlineColor,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=CNIsOnline,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="{x:Null}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},Path=DataContext.UnknownColor,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

However, I still get binding errors and I just see a 50x50 box as the tooltip.

Here are the binding errors:

```
System.Windows.Data Information: 41 : BindingExpression path error: 'userimg' property not found for 'object' because data item is null.  This could happen because the data provider has not produced any data yet. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
System.Windows.Data Information: 20 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value due to missing information. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
System.Windows.Data Information: 21 : BindingExpression cannot retrieve value from null data item. This could happen when binding is detached or when binding to a Nullable type that has no value. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead. BindingExpression:Path=userimg; DataItem=null; target element is 'Image' (Name=''); target property is 'Source' (type 'ImageSource')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't edit code you post.
I had to delete the original post and create another just to change binding to dynamicresouree.

Comment: I updated the OP to reflect the current state, it still doesn't like the bindings for some reason. :(

Comment: Except if you put that line elsewhere in your xaml it works. But not when you do it now. So what is different between then and now?

Comment: as a test, I placed <Image x:Key="yuserimg" Height="50" Width="50" Source="{Binding userimg}"/> in my page resources at the top of my XAML.  Then I placed ToolTip="{DynamicResource yuserimg}" in one of my other controls and the image is there. It's like the binding in my <DataGrid.Resources> doesn't like 'userimg' for some reason.